# ASP.Net Razor App - OAuth somehow got into app, can't get it out

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, razor

Sounds strange, I know... and I've poured over every post I could find relating to this :(  However, my website worked just fine and then all of the sudden it is failing on:

> Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version 4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the asembly reference. (Exception from HResult: 0x80131040).

I don't see any references to it at all in the project and it has never used authentication ever. What is the lowest level I can get to in order to find out where it is trying to call this assembly and remove it?

It's frustrating as heck... I know it is because I'm not an every-day programmer - so maybe its easy to find, but I have looked over hundreds of posts here and elsewhere trying to resolve and nothing has worked so far :(

[image: References in Project]

[image: Nuget Package Manager]

I also grabbed an unused reference tool called ResolveUR to try to do it... still same result :(

FYI - I'm using Visual Studio 2013 for this one because Installshield LE is part of it and that was how the application was initially deployed.

Thanks in advance!

** ADDED error I get from page **

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/MedsAdmin/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MedsAdmin\bin
Calling assembly : Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/medsadmin/4efeacc2/d291dc53/DotNetOpenAuth.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/medsadmin/4efeacc2/d291dc53/DotNetOpenAuth.Core/DotNetOpenAuth.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/MedsAdmin/bin/DotNetOpenAuth.Core.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

*** EDIT:  Replaced Old Web.Config ***

Somehow my web.config file got written over - so that is the reason for the OpenAuth issue.

**NOW:**  It seems to be trying to load MySQLMembershipProvider from my machine.config file **(which fails)**.  Why is it doing this?

Comment: I can't see image but this could happen if you are using a 3rd party dll that relies on it. You can also open up .vbproj file in notepad and see if you can find it there.

Comment: I don't see anything in the .vbproj relating to OAuth.  I do not have any 3rd party dlls at all.  The only thing I even changed before I re-compiled was a SQL statement (text) in the vbhtml file :(

Comment: I hadn't because that shouldn't have changed with the install (well, at least I wouldn't think so).  I can't find the 2780ccd10d57b246 in the machine.config file it is pointing to.  I do see the 31bf3856ad364e35.  Is that what I should be looking for?

Comment: It seems that somehow my web.config got wiped out :(  I restored that and I'm closer... but now the machine.config is trying to load MySQLMembershipProvider and I'm unsure why as it isn't part of my project and never was.